# stuck on boot-loop

Tags: adb, boot-loop, unbricking, xiaomi, magisk

I experimented with custom roms, my phone cant load system, i get the start vibration with redmi screen looped. I have redmi note 9 pro max, i got lineage os 18.1 working for month, i tired upgrading to 19.1, i suspect that it could have been Magisk ive tried to flash on my phone that caused it, ive been for hours downloading different roms and magisk versions to try to find combination thats working, i need help, i think i want to reset the phone to how it was before the magisk but i dont know the words that i need to google for solution, my guess is something wrong with boot image- but i dont know what it means.
i tried looking online how to uninstall magisk, but tutorials are outdated, i cant use TWRP because theres no version for my phone

Answer (score 0):

First of all is your device boot into recovery mode or not ? if it is then, just wipe data, system, cache, meta and whatever then connect your device to pc copy paste your customrom.zip then flash. If your device didnt boot into recovery then download miui fastboot rom and mi flash tool install necessary drivers and then, extract the rom zip in pc, goto fastboot mode into your mobile. Connect usb cable to your laptop, then run mi flash tool as admin select the extracted folder path in miflash tool, refresh to check if th device is connected to your laptop. The flash. It will erase all your data and install official stock rom to your device.

Comment: i did do hundred wipes when trying different roms+magisks versions. anyways i already did the mi flash tool, it looked like it didnt do anything, after status turnt finish i tried to reboot phone and now its even worse then before. phone turns on for 1 second then black over and over, no fastboot/ recovery anymore. this is where i gave up